# fetch data from database and plot it on google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have an index page that has 2 drop down. second dropdown depends on the first one, after selecting a value from the second list, a search is performed through the database table acc to the value selected and then the matching result is displayed. what i want is that the result that is getting dispalyed(in this case the latitude and longitude corresponding the result) should be shown on google map

code that i have so far

Code on the main page that contains the dropdown and will display the map

```
<div class="showsearch" id="gmap_canvas">  //place where the ,ap should get displayed
</div>
```

Code that performs the search to display result and should also work for map

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['fname']))
    {
        $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);

        $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM features_for_office WHERE fname LIKE "%'.$fname.'%"';
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    {
                        $latitude= $row["latitude"];
                        $longitude= $row["longitude"];
                    }
                    ?>


                    <!-- JavaScript to show google map -->


<div class="showsearch" id="gmap_canvas"></div> 
        <script>
        function init_map(lat,lang) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
        });
        /*infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>"
        });*/
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    function loadCoordinates(){
        var latitude;
        var longitude;
               $('.showsearch').blur(function() {
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "get_search_data.php",
                data: "name="+$(this).val(),
                success: function(json){
                $('#number').val(json.num);
                }
              });
         });
        //call the function once coordinates are available from the server/
        //init_map must be called from the call back of ajax function
        init_map(latitude,longitude);
    }
    //instead of init_map call the loadCoordinates to get the values from server
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadCoordinates);

                        </script>

       <?php }
        else 
            {
                echo "0 results";
            }
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

although i am getting the value of latitude and longitude but i am not able to display a map along with markers on specific latitude and longitudes. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your div and php script is on the same page itself, correct ?

Comment: @Shaikh Mohammed Shariq no they are on different page

Comment: Your map gets rendered in the div you have specified with id "gmap_canvas". Your script to load the map should be on the same page where you have specified the div as your div is the container. If your php page renders the response page for map than you can define the div just above the java script tag to show the map.

Check the example here of Javascript + HTML where div and javascript are on the same page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are retrieving the coordinate values from server you can modify your map rendering code to load the map based on latitude-longitude values retrieved from server through AJAX. On your page on which you want to show the map you can have below mentioned code.

```
<div class="showsearch" id="gmap_canvas"> </div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init_map(lat,lang) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
        });
        /*infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>"
        });*/
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    function loadCoordinates(){
         $('.showsearch').blur(function() {
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "get_search_data.php",
                data: "name="+$(this).val(),
                success: function(json){

                   var latitude;
                   var longitude;
                   latitude = LATITUDE_VALUE_FROM_SERVER;
                   longitude = LONGTITUDE_VALUE_FROM_SERVER;
                   init_map(latitude,longitude);
                }
              });
         });
    }
    //instead of init_map call the loadCoordinates to get the values from server
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadCoordinates);
</script>
```

You will require to retrieve the coordinate values from the server using an ajax call and in the call back of ajax function call the function to load the map.

Comment: i have edited the post under <!--javascript to show the google map--> can u plz gp thru it, coz even after editing and combing the div and google map code on same page i am not getting the result

Comment: @Sam I have edited my answer, please check success function and make sure you set the latitude and longitude values correctly which is received from server.